# http port 80 slow, while other ports are fine

Tags: http, adsl

I am using ADSL2+, and the sustained connection can go up to 1.3MB/s,
but recently the HTTP connection has been quite slow ( other port i.e. ftp, torrent, etc are fine).

I am using Netgear modem/router for my ADSL connection, and am using Netgear switches for my LAN (connected to the modem).

What can go wrong and how can I investigate?

Answer (score 3):

Any possibility that your ISP could be using transparent proxies to route web traffic? I've a WiMAX connection where this happens. The web traffic is routed through a web proxy at the ISP's end. I get slow speeds when browsing, but fast speeds when using any other services. I have started using an SSH tunnel to re-route my web traffic, and sure enough, have seen faster speeds.

Comment: Not sure. I guess I have to ask my ISP

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you are hosting a HTTP service and people are complaining it's slow or do you mean you are trying to browse the Internet and this is were you see it is slow ? If the former, it is due to your upload rate. If the latter, maybe that's because of DNS resolution ?

Comment: It is the latter. how can I check my DNS connection?

Comment: You could try to nslookup a few well-known domains for example (using your ISP DNS servers).

Comment: You should most likely clear the DNS cache before you do those tests

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [Speedtest.Net](http://www.speedtest.net/) for checking your bandwidth availability
2. Try [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/start/) to check if your ISP DNS is not in good shape
   The Basic form is free.
   This is how you can [setup your computer to use it](https://store.opendns.com/setup/computer/).

Answer (score 0):

It was all ok now, so I can only assume that it was my ISP's fault that it was slow on port 80.